# How to specify linux binary's rpath in cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, makefile, rpath

I have a CMakeLists.txt file that contains such line of code:

```
link_directories(dir_a dir_b dir_c)
```

When I build an executable and perform

```
readelf -d
```

on it, I see RPATH with dir_a, dir_b dir_c.

What can I do with cmake if I want to create

- Executable with empty RPATH?
- Executable with some paths, but not specified in link_directories line?

The executable is not supposed to be "installed".

Answer (score 2):

From this [cmake-documentation](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling#CMake_and_the_RPATH) you can read that:

- you can use the variable `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH` to have cmake not adding any RPATH to a binary ever and
- that with the `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES`-functions RPATHs can be controlled individually on a per-target base.